# Set and Change data in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using latest ag-grid in angular-6.

I want to set data in ag-grid from subscribed data of Angular service. The response of the service is like this:

```
{
  "summaryData": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "tabularData": [
    {
      "fld1": "val1",
      "fld2": "val2"
    },
    {
      "fld1": "val3",
      "fld2": "val5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to assign the `tabularData` to ag-grid.

I have followed tutorial from ag-grid but somehow unable to get the data shown in the grid.

I have attempted the following.

HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid 
style="width: 100%; height: 220px;" 
[enableColResize]="true" 
[animateRows]="true"
class="ag-theme-balham mt-8" 
[enableSorting]="true" 
[enableFilter]="true" 
[columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
[pagination]="true"
[rowData] = "rowData | async">

</ag-grid-angular>
```

TS:

```
populateGrid() {
 this.myService.getAllData(this.selectedId)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          
    this.rowData = response.tabularData;
  });
}
```

ag-grid gets stuck at `Loading...` even after getting data from the service (checked in network tab of chrome developer tools)

Comment: Why are you using the `async` pipe here: `[rowData] = "rowData | async">` when you already have `subscribe`d to the Observable in your Component Class? Try removing the `async` pipe and check if it works.

Comment: @SiddAjmera [you don't need to use `| async` pipe if you are  using `subscribe`](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/05/async-pipe-versus-subscribe-in-angular.html).

@Lakshman Pilaka, pls provide a full sample with plnkr and will see what is an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @SiddAjmera in the comments, I have removed `| async` pipe from my view:

```
[rowData] = "rowData"
```

I am now able to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async pipe:

```
[rowData] = "rowData | async"
```

only when your rowData is Observable for example:

```
populateGrid() {
 rowData = this.myService.getAllData(this.selectedId); // you should not subscribe it does async pipe for you implicitly 
}
```